# Groovy: Find/return the value of a map by key in a list of maps

Tags: dictionary, groovy, collections

I have a list of maps and I want to get a specific map on the list and return its value for a given key.
I'm sure there is something fundamental I am missing, but I cannot make this work. I have several failed attempts:

```
void "find map by key in a list of maps"() {
        given: "a list of maps"
        List favorites = [
                [fruit: 'apple'],
                [color: 'yellow'],
                [activity: 'reading']]

        when:
        String favoriteColor = favorites.each {
            it.find { key, value ->
                key == 'color'
                return value
            }
        }

//        String favoriteColor = favorites.each { it['color'] }
//        String favoriteColor = favorites.find { it.key == 'color' }
//        String favoriteColor = favorites.collect { it['color'] }
//        String favoriteColor = favorites*.get('color')
//        String favoriteColor = favorites*.get('color').value
//        String favoriteColor = favorites.collect { it['color'] }.value as String
//        String favoriteColor = favorites.find { it['color'] }.value as String

        then:
        favoriteColor == 'yellow'
    }
```

Is there a clean way to make this work?

Comment: `key == 'color'` - this doesn't do anything.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it does in the context of a `find` closure

Comment: @tim_yates - Only as an implied `return` - this closure has an explicit `return` though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ***blush*** you're right... My apologies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do

```
String favoriteColour = favorites.findResult { it.color }
```